# Samba4 Bind9 client registration as A Host

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-14.04, samba4

I have setup an AD DC using Samba4 with Bind9. Everything works perfectly. The problem I'm seeing is after joining a computer to the domain, the computer doesn't appear in DNS as a Host (A) compared to Microsoft that it automatically add the computer to the list.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Are you able to see the computer in the DNS upon domain join?

Thanks.

Stan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Samba** has the capability to automatically update the **BIND** zone files via Kerberos.

You have to configure **bind** with **auto update**.

Check this article for full configuration and integration between Bind and Samba as domain controller [Samba/Active Directory domain controller](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samba/Active_Directory_domain_controller)

Comment: I wish I had read this days ago. My issue with the update is already solved. It was a permission issue on the apparmor and the zone. Thank you!

Comment: Another thing, have you encountered issues with Skype for Business and Outlook client configuration for O365? When I join a Client to the domain using the same DNS, it is unable to connect. Unjoined clients are able to connect. Any thoughts? Thanks.